# MOS Common-Source stage with source degeneration

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

I read about the common-source stage with source degeneration in Razavi's book. I understand that is the small-signal gain of the overall circuit becomes less dependent on gm (hence Vin) and thus the gain is a lot more linear.

My confusion is that I don't understand how from a large-signal perspective, the drain current becomes linearised and has a slope equal to 1/Rs as shown below:

[image]

Can anyone explain to me how 1/Rs comes about from the large-signal equations? Razavi only talks about the small-signal perspective.

Comment: Notice that if Vin >> Vgs then Id ≈ Vin/Rs. Do you see it?

Comment: I see it from the KVL but I don't understand this fully. How can Vin >> Vgs? Vgs is by definition = Vin - RsId .... Oh! If Id is large enough, then Vgs will small compared to Vin. Ah! So that's what Razavi meant by saying "Most of Vin is dropped across Rs". So that 1/Rs slope is really only valid for large drain currents??

Comment: For small-signal it will also be true if 1/gm < Rs